# How to Find Solution to this Question using Modular Arithmetic

Tags: number-theory

Tomorrow is the annual local Summer Fair. You want to make smoothies to sell, but you would also like to make one cake for the raffle. Each smoothie requires 23g of strawberries, and you also need 150g of strawberries for your cake. The market only sells strawberries in packets of 100g, and you do not want anything to go to waste.

What is the smallest number of packets you need to buy in order for there to be no waste?

Comment: Right. What did you try?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$100k - 150 \equiv 0 {\pmod {23}}$

$100k \equiv 150 {\pmod {23}}$

$2k \equiv 3 {\pmod {23}}$

$k = \frac{23m + 3}{2}$

$k = 13$

$1300 = 50 \times 23 + 150$

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56766700/how-do-i-solve-this-easy-dynamic-programming-problem.....................Can you help me with this dynamic programming problem??  @גלעד ברקן

Comment: Can you explain me the algorithm of this problem :                            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61082584/maximum-matching-for-line-graphs